# failture in CMD batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In Windows cmd batch,
I try to call a batch file:

```
call ".\%%R\scenery\list bgl.bat" ".\%%R\scenery\"
```

In the "list bgl.bat" I have:

```
IF "%1"=="" ( dir *.bgl /b > list_bgl.txt ) ELSE  ( dir "%1*.bgl" /b > list_bgl.txt )
```

and it crashes somewhere in the place of condition. The if true part works OK (if I run the batch "list bgl.bat" directly). But If I run it from a batch file, so the else block fails and the script crashes. Do see where is problem?

Update:

```
T:\test\scenery>call ".\list bgl.bat"
T:\test\scenery>IF "" == "" (dir *.bgl /b   1>list_bgl.txt )  ELSE (dir "*.bgl" /b   1>list_bgl.txt )
T:\test\scenery>ECHO DONE
DONE

T:\test\scenery>pause
Press any key to continue

T:\test\scenery>call ".\list bgl.bat" ".\"
T:\test\scenery>IF ".\" == ""
(dir *.bgl /b   1>list_bgl.txt )  ELSE (dir ".\*.bgl" /b   1>list_bgl.txt )
T:\test\scenery>ECHO DONE
DONE

T:\test\scenery>pause
Press any key to continue
T:\test\scenery>
```

Well this works. Command parametr no. 1 was tested from cmd-line

EDIT2:
When I call the main batch (from parent directory) I see no error, but **the file is not created in the specified directory but in the main directory from where the main run was performed:**

:

```
@echo off
cls
for /F "tokens=*" %%R in ('dir * /A:D /b') do (
echo ".\%%R\scenery\list bgl.bat"
call ".\%%R\scenery\list bgl.bat" ".\%%R\scenery\"
)
pause
```

EDIT3:
Yeah, I have it. Problem here:

```
 > list_bgl.txt
```

I miss the path there... This works:

```
IF "%~1"=="" ( dir *.bgl /b > list_bgl.txt ) ELSE ( dir "%~1*.bgl" /b > "%~1list_bgl.txt" )
```

Comment: what if you run the "list bgl.bat" with the parameter? like: `"list bgl.bat" "dummy parameter"`

Comment: Well I try and must update my post. See above

Comment: Did you realized that `".\%%R\scenery\"` path is exactly the same as `"%%R\scenery\"`? The dot mean "current directory" so ".\Anydir" is Anydir below current directory...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already enclosing your parameter in quotes during the call, then you add a second set of quotes within "list bgl.bat". That can cause problems. If you want to add enclosing quotes within "list bgl.bat" then you need to first remove any possible existing enclosing quotes using `%~1`.

```
IF "%~1"=="" ( dir *.bgl /b > list_bgl.txt ) ELSE  ( dir "%~1*.bgl" /b > list_bgl.txt )
```

**update**
You have shown an example of what works, but we need to see what is not working. The quote / %~ issue was real, but it looks like you have something else that is causing problems. I'm curious what the run-time value of %%R is? I'm also surprised that the path to your called batch file can vary.

Comment: The path can vary but I test it only in one sub-folder. Sorry, that I did more edits of my post. So in the last update I wrote, everything works, but the file is created not in the right path (sub-subdirectory). The file is created in the T:\ ... which is the path where I run the main bat.

Comment: So finaly, problem was here: 1) I added the ~ character to filter quotes (thanx dbenham) 2) I added path ( arg 1 ) before >   3) I needed to overwrite the old version of the subscript which is included in other directories. Because I run more scripts like this, so the old version created a file in parent directory... Now it is OK. The files are created in the sub folder :-)